# Cannot install netbeans on Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, netbeans, compile

I'm trying to install Netbeans on my Gentoo system and I just cannot get it to work. When I'm compiling it It fails due to not being able to locate org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.

> [nb-javac] class file for org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject not found

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the installation not being able to find several files. However these are reported as warnings. The missing files have a version in their filenames, the files that are on the disk have a version number that is slightly off. So that explains why these cannot be found.

The full output of the install can be found here: http://pastebin.com/43NS2ktz

Answer (score 0):

```
tryggve ~ # eix maven
* app-admin/eselect-maven
     Available versions:  ~0.1 0.2 0.2-r1
     Homepage:            http://www.gentoo.org/
     Description:         Manages Maven symlinks

* dev-java/maven-bin
     Available versions:
        (1.1)   1.1-r1 ~1.1-r3
        (2.0)   2.0.11 ~2.0.11-r2
        (2.2)   2.2.1 ~2.2.1-r2
        (3.0)   ~3.0.4-r1
        {{elibc_FreeBSD}}
     Homepage:            http://maven.apache.org/
     Description:         Project Management and Comprehension Tool for Java
```

Install maven and use the first package to select the proper version.